# How to use Linq's Select method and pass each entity to automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

In my ASP.NET MVC project, I have a HttpGET method where I need to get a list of vehicles from the DB. It's straightforward, simply get the data and pass the list to view. But I am following a tutorial from udemy ( asp.net MVC 5 complete) where the author uses Automapper to automatically map objects with their Dtos. In the tutorial its was Automapper version 4.1 but I am using version 7.x. So in my get Method I am not able to understand how to write the Linq query to get all the vehicles and Map each one to its dto and send as the list.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<VehicleDto> GetVehicles()
{
     return _context.Vehicles.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<Vehicle,VehicleDto>(**How can I send each object here**));
     //return _context.Vehicles.ToList();
}
```

I have gone through the help docs in Automapper and was unable to find a proper example, or rather I didn't understand how to apply that material to solve my problem please help.

Comment: Collections are handled by default, there is no need for select.

Comment: Do you want to return a collection of `Vehicle` or `VehicleDto`?

Comment: @RuiJarimba I want to fill Dto from vehicle model which is filled from DB.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu yes but then how do I know that I am usng dto to pass on data to view?

Comment: ```Mapper.Map<List<VehicleDto>>(_context.Vehicles)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `_context.Vehicles.ToList()` returns an `IList<Vehicle>`, you could do the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<VehicleDto> GetVehicles()
{
    return Mapper.Map<IList<Vehicle>, List<VehicleDto>>(_context.Vehicles.ToList());
}
```

This also assumes you've configured your mapping from `Vehicle` to `VehicleDto` using something like the following:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Vehicle, VehicleDto>();
```

Alternatively, you could use LINQ's select operator and do the following to call `Map` on individual items rather than on the entire collection:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<VehicleDto> GetVehicles()
{
    return _context.Vehicles.Select(v => Mapper.Map<Vehicle, VehicleDto>(v)).ToList();
}
```

**Updated:**  Switched `Vehicle` and `VehicleDto` to reflect information revealed in comment by OP indicating that he stores data as `Vehicle` in the database and his method should return a list of `VehicleDto`.

Comment: It could be that `VehicleDto` and `Vehicle` need to be swapped places everywhere, it would not make much sense if the `DbContext` returned `VehicleDto` objects (unless it turns out that OP has used the name VehicleDto for the Entity class)

Comment: I'd use `ProjectTo` here (in the last example). EF will complain that `Mapper.Map` isn't supported in an EF query, but mostly because `ProjectTo` was made for this.

Comment: Yes I have Created Map for both source to dto and dto to source.Here I am getting the values from underlying DB, which exactly matches the Vehicle class,whereas VehicleDto is what is returned fromthe method to isolate the client and underlying model.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have your mapper class defined previously?

You load the class in the startup.

1. App_Start folder. Create a class named MapModelEntity.cs

   `public class MapModelEntity
   {
       public static void RegisterMapping()
       {
           Mapper.Initialize(config =>
           {
             config.CreateMap<StatusEntity, StatusTypeModel>().ReverseMap(); // For bothways
             config.CreateMap<Vehicle, VehicleDto>() // For custom mapping
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop1,
                              opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Prop1)); 
           }`
2. Add a reference to Global.asax

   `protected void Application_Start()
   {
           GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
           AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
           FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
           RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
           BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
           **MapModelEntity.RegisterMapping();**
   }`
3. In controller

   `var Result = _context.Vehicles.ToList();
   var Mapped = Mapper.Map<VehicleDto>(Result);`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the way you presented, I have already created the mapping but since I am following old tutorials your code is really helpful to me now...Thanks a lot

Comment: Also I can'yt vote up because I have not got that much reputation.